# JQuery Validation not working if select box option changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have a form on submitting of which i check if certain type of option is selected my validation changes according to it but its not working somehow can any body help me Here is my HTML of form:

```
<form method="post" id="addnews" action="/app/index.php/admin/sizes/save" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-top:0px" name="addnews">
        <table width="100%" class="font">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td colspan="2"><span style="color: rgb(204, 0, 0); padding-left: 302px;">( Note:Fields marked with * are required )</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:301px;text-align:right; vertical-align:top;"><label><font size="4" color="Red">*</font>&nbsp;Size Type: </label></td>
                <td style="text-align:left">
                   <select onchange="getForm(this.value);" style="width:206px;" name="size_type" id="size_type" class="common_form">
                        <option value="0">Template</option><option value="1"> Wallart</option>                  </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="display:block inline;" id="templateForm" class="font">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right; vertical-align:middle;">
                                <label><font size="4" color="Red">*</font>&nbsp;Name: </label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:left">
                                <input type="text" value="" maxlength="200" id="name" name="name" class="common_form">
                                                                <label style="display:none;" id="name_lbl">Please enter name</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right; vertical-align:top;"><label><font size="4" color="Red">*</font>&nbsp;Code: </label></td>
                            <td style="text-align:left">
                               <input type="text" value="" maxlength="200" id="code" name="code" class="common_form">        
                                                           <label style="display:none;" id="code_lbl">Please enter code</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right; vertical-align:top;"><label><font size="4" color="Red">*</font>&nbsp;Num Code: </label></td>
                            <td style="text-align:left">
                               <input type="text" value="" maxlength="200" id="num_code" name="num_code" class="common_form">
                                                           <label style="display:none;" id="numc_lbl">Please enter num code</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                                        <table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="display:none;" id="wallartForm" class="font">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right; vertical-align:middle;width:299px;">
                                <label><font size="4" color="Red">*</font>&nbsp;Width: </label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align:left">
                                <input type="text" value="" maxlength="200" id="width" name="width" class="common_form">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right; vertical-align:top;"><label><font size="4" color="Red">*</font>&nbsp;Height: </label></td>
                            <td style="text-align:left">
                               <input type="text" value="" maxlength="200" id="height" name="height" class="common_form">        
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>            
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right"><label>Status: </label></td>
                <td style="text-align:left">
                    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="1" name="is_active">Active
                    <input type="radio" value="0" name="is_active">Inactive
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td style="text-align:left">
                    <input type="hidden" value="" name="id" id="id">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="submitT" onclick="if($('#size_type').val() == 1){check('W',this.form);}else{check('T',this.form);}" class="button115_a">

                    <input type="button" onclick="back();" value="Back" class="button90_b">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </form>
```

On Selectbox change i hide certain fields of form also reset my form if any validation was previously done:

```
function getForm(id)
{
        var validator = $("#addnews").validate();
        validator.resetForm();
    if(id == 1)
    {
        $("#templateForm").attr("style","display:none;");
        $("#wallartForm").attr("style","display:block inline;");

    }
    else
    {
        $("#templateForm").attr("style","display:block inline;");
        $("#wallartForm").attr("style","display:none;");


    }
}
```

This is my validation function:

```
function check(type){


            if(type == "T"){

            $('#addnews').validate({
            rules: {
                name:{required:true},
                code:{required:true},
                num_code:{required:true}
            },
            messages:{
                name:{required:"<br>Please enter size name"},
                code:{required:"<br>Please enter size code"},
                num_code:{required:"<br>Please enter size num code"}
            }
        });
            }
            else{
                alert("yes")
                $('#addnews').validate({
            rules: {
                width:{required:true},
                height:{required:true}

            },
            messages:{
                width:{required:"<br>Please enter width"},
                height:{required:"<br>Please enter height"}

            }
        });

            }


        }
```

The Validation applies on Template Selection but not working on wallart Selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lot easier than you think - the jQuery validate plugin ignores hidden fields by default, giving you the functionality you need 'out of the box'.  What you need to do is

firstly make sure you have a version of the plugin >= 1.9.0, then

1. set up your validation for the whole form
2. hide and show the two parts of the form with your getForm(...) function
3. let jQuery validate do the rest

(so you don't need your check(...) function)

keeping your html the same, replace your script with this

```
<script>

function getForm(id) {
    if (id == 1) {
        $("#templateForm").attr("style", "display:none;");
        $("#wallartForm").attr("style", "display:block inline;");

    }
    else {
        $("#templateForm").attr("style", "display:block inline;");
        $("#wallartForm").attr("style", "display:none;");
    }
}


$(function () {
    $('#addnews').validate({
        rules: {
            name: { required: true },
            code: { required: true },
            num_code: { required: true },
            width: { required: true },
            height: { required: true }
        },
        messages: {
            name: { required: "<br>Please enter size name" },
            code: { required: "<br>Please enter size code" },
            num_code: { required: "<br>Please enter size num code" },
            width: { required: "<br>Please enter width" },
            height: { required: "<br>Please enter height" }
        },
        submitHandler: function () {
            alert('form is valid');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: not working actually it does applying validation on hidden elements as well i checked the version of jquery validation as well

Comment: sorry, you need to remove the onclick handler from your submit button.  fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/3pp6Y/1/

Comment: Thanks I don't know why its not working in my Project but It surely is the correct answer as i tested it on jsfiddle Thanks mate for your helping